# HttpResponse ClientProtocolExecption

Tags: java, android

I have an HttpGet that has been working just fine.  Recently the webpage changed where I get the information from.  I am basically reading the text from the page for song metadata from a shoutcast server.  This new URL will not allow the HttpResponse response = client.execute(method) to run on this new url.  It immediately throws the clientprotocolexception with no further information so I have no idea what is going wrong.  I downloaded wireshark.  This is the response: HTTP/1.0 200 OK.  The old url response is HTTP/1.1 200 OK.  I have googled for hours now and have not been able to find any help.

Does anyone have a suggestion or have any help on this?

Here is the code:

```
package com.joebutt.mouseworldradio;

import java.io.*;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.client.*;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.*;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;


import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;


public class HttpMetaData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
{

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params)
{
    Log.d("MWR MetaData", "doInBackground called");
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet method = new HttpGet("http://wdwtoday.serverroom.us:4152/7.html");
    //HttpGet method = new HttpGet("http://38.96.148.18:4152/7.html");
    //method.setHeader("HTTP/1.1", "200 OK");
    //method.setHeader("Content-Type:", "text/html");
    //old url that worked just fine for 2 years
    //HttpGet method = new HttpGet("http://yp.shoutcast.com/Metadata_Info1.php?surl=" + Play.selectedUrl);
    String responseData = "";
    if(isCancelled())
    {
        return responseData;
    }
    try
    {
        //fails at the response!!
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(method);
        int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        String statusString = Integer.toString(status);
        Log.d("MWR Http status code", statusString);
        if (status == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
        {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
            InputStream inStream = entity.getContent();
            int numBytes = inStream.read(buffer);
            inStream.close();
            responseData = new String(buffer,0,numBytes);

            //get rid of the first part of the string
            if(responseData.length() > 13)
            {
                responseData = responseData.substring(13);

                //now get rid of the end of the string to clean it up
                //int length = responseData.length();
                int endPoint = responseData.indexOf("'");
                responseData = responseData.substring(0, endPoint);

                //old stuff wasnt used 8/2014
                //if (Play.selectedUrl.equals("http://38.96.148.91:4152"))
                //{
                    //int trimAmount = length - 37;
                    //responseData = responseData.substring(0, trimAmount);
                //}
                //else if (Play.selectedUrl.equals("http://38.96.148.91:4154"))
                //{
                //  int trimAmount = length - 31;
                    //responseData = responseData.substring(0, trimAmount);
                //}
            }
            else
            {
                responseData = "Data is not currently available";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            responseData = "Data is not currently available";
        }
    }
    catch(ClientProtocolException e)
    {
        Log.d("MWR MetaData", "Response Failure: " + e + "/" + responseData);
        responseData = "Data Error";
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        Log.d("MWR MetaData", "IOException" + e + "/" + responseData);
        responseData = "Data is not currently available";
    }

    return responseData;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
{

    Play.metaData=result;
    Log.d("MWR getMetaData", "onPostExecute Called");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Ok so with help in the WinAmp forum I found out that this url needs to be requested with the user agent "Mozilla".

So I added:

```
method.setHeader("User-Agent","Mozilla");
```

And now I get a 200 OK response.

Maybe this will help someone else with this type of problem.

Joe